# How to implement refresh token in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, token

I have followed this guide https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/ to implement access tokens in my web application and it is working fine. However, this guide does not mention anything about refresh token.

Can anyone help me out on how to implement this in Java Spring Boot? Or is there any other way to keep a user logged in?

Comment: By design, your user is not 'logged in' since JWT is stateless. I recommend a full understanding of JWT mechanisms and purpose before trying to implement it using java, spring, nodejs or whatever

Answer (score 6):

Spring provides the functionality for getting a new access token if you configured it correctly, i.e if `authorizedGrantTypes` contains `"refresh_code"`.

You should use the refresh token to get a new access token by using the token endpoint like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [base64encode(clientId:clientSecret)]" "https://yourdomain.com/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[yourRefreshToken]"
```

example:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Basic dGVzdGNsaWVudDpzZWNyZXQ=' -d 'refresh_token=fdb8fdbecf1d03ce5e6125c067733c0d51de209c&grant_type=refresh_token' localhost:3000/oauth/token

{
    "token_type":"bearer",
"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiVlx1MDAxNcKbwoNUwoonbFPCu8KhwrYiLCJpYXQiOjE0NDQyNjI4NjYsImV4cCI6MTQ0NDI2Mjg4Nn0.Dww7TC-d0teDAgsmKHw7bhF2THNichsE6rVJq9xu_2s",
"expires_in":20,
"refresh_token":"7fd15938c823cf58e78019bea2af142f9449696a"
}
```

as described here: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/